# How to display the currency field in visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce-template

Mutilple Currencies is enabled in Org. Default -USD

Ex : i am having currency value__c(datatype - currency) field .if the GBP is selected the amount will be displayed as GBP 1000 (USD 1316)

When i am trying to display the currency field in visualforce email template it is populating the GBP 1000. how to populate USD value in Email.

Answer (score 0):

this might helps

```
 <apex:outputText label="NRR" value="{0,number}">
{! Opportunity.CurrencyIsoCode} &nbsp;
<apex:param value="{! Opportunity.NRR__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: If iam mentioning its not showing up the USD value . The output is like GBP 1000 . But i need display only the dollar value in the email